# How to enable contextual links for views content panes?

Tags: views, panels, chaos-tool-suite

If I do not enable module "Views content panes", I see all block generated by Views in  "Miscellaneous" category. When I insert such block in my panels, contextual links are displayed well fore each block.

But If I enable "Views content panes" module, all views are moved to "Views" category and disappear from "Miscellaneous" category. I get some additional options, but I miss contextual links: no contextual links rendered for views.

How to output contextual links for views inserted with "Views content panes"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For contextual links to show, you need to create a content pane in your view. +Add > Content Pane. There will be a new panels category automatically created called "View Panes".